Indexing Empty Collection seems slow on my Mac
I'm running community edition (v7) on latest Mac OS version (Intel Mac).  This is a nodejs application with a lot of tests that I've written and each set of tests creates a new DB and several collections with indexes before it runs that test.
The bottleneck is creating the indexes.  It's taking around 4 seconds to do this and it didn't seem so bad until one of my developers who uses windows ran the tests and I noticed his ran much faster, especially when creating the indexes.
So I have been back an forth with chatgpt and the mongodb doc about different things I can try and nothing really moves the needle. It's always around 4 seconds, which wouldn't be terrible one at a time but when I run a full regression it's 30 tests.  Also it wouldn't seem out of line if there was something to index.  These are always empty databases.
Any ideas?  I've tried all the settings in mongodb that I can find and turned spotlight index off on the db directory...
Index creation looks like this:
    module.exports.createViews = async (db) => { 
      try { 
        const collectionsWithIndexes = [ 
         { name: 'lead', indexes: [ {key: {'match.ts': 1}, background: true}, 
         {key: {'match.buyer': 1, 'match.ts': 1}, background: true}, 
         {key: {source: 1, ts: 1}, background: true}, 
        .... ] 
       
       await Promise.all( 
          collectionsWithIndexes.map(async (col) => { 
            await db.createCollection(col.name) 
            await db.collection(col.name).createIndexes(col.indexes) }) 
       ) 
       } 
    }


This might be better suited at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ However, it needs debugging details to be looked into.

Are you submitting the index builds one at a time or using the bulk method

Please edit your question for such code instead of putting it into a comment.

I spun up an ubuntu vm on my Mac and installed mongodb community edition with no special setting.  right out of the box.  >10X faster index creation than the Mac side.  So narrowed it down to my homebrew installation of mongodb is definitely the problem.  I also tried reinstalling homebrew installation...no change.  I think next I will try a non-homebrew install on Mac and see what that brings.
